# VSO build does not copy output to the drop folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I've been spending the last couple days trying to get our automated build and deployment sorted out but the build process seems to be a bit broken for some reason.

I was trying the "Copy build output to the server" staging location for a bit but if I downloaded the drop .zip it would just be an empty folder.

I switched it over to being put in a source control folder, but after a build it's the same; all that's in the drop folder is some log files.

The only error I've got is the following line:

"TF270003: Failed to copy. Ensure the source directory C:\a\bin exists and that you have the appropriate permissions."

Any insights on this? I don't think there's really anything I can do about build permissions on VSO, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Have you tried to run vs as administrator?

Comment: This is an issue with builds kicked off on Visual Studio Online (formerly Team Foundation Service I think), not local builds. Incidentally, I do run VS as administrator.

Comment: What does your build make? Are you sure that there are bits being pushed to the drop folder.

Answer (score 0):

To test out either it is the system or your code that is not producing any output can you create a post build PowerShell script and have it create a blank readme.txt file in the root of the drop.

https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/CustomActivities/blob/master/Source/Scripts/GatherItemsForDrop.ps1

You can use the script above as a guide.

If your bits don't normally provide ant output the you need to build the drop folder yourself.

If you are still stuck you can install a local/azure build agent connected to your VSO and debug there.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the attempts. Turns out it was because setting the output to "AsConfigured" doesn't actually do what it sounds like it does. I had to change it to "SingleFolder" and then it copied everything over great.

The error in this case is not particularly helpful.